# Loading Point Layers on Smartphone

Tags: qgis, point

i calculated some Pointlayers with Qgis and i want to find them in the field. Can i load these points including the GPS-data on mysSmartphone and use it as a GPS-device? Are there any Apps?

Comment: GPS Essentials is a good Android app which supports kml, kmz & gpx files and should do what you want. Alternatively, you could try QField and export your whole QGIS project.

Comment: @BenW that comment seems good enough to post as an answer

Comment: Thanks @csk. I have expanded my comment slightly and posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you export to KML/KMZ you can load them directly into Google Maps via MyMaps (https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3024836?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). You need a Google account but if you don't already have one it's free and easy to sign up. I've used a couple of different apps (primarily GISCloud) to work with GIS data in the field, but if all you need is a map interface with a point layer overlay (ie. you don't need to do any data collection etc.), nothing beats a familiar UI and a high-confidence basemap.

Answer (score 1):

GPS Essentials is a good, free GPS app for Android devices which supports kml, kmz & gpx files and should do what you want. Alternatively, you could use QField and export your whole QGIS project. While QField is primarily a field data collection & visualisation tool (as opposed to a GPS app) it does have a nice positioning feature which centres the map view on a marker of the users current location which updates and moves in real time, so navigating to point features is relatively easy.